# Repetition while execution of getElementsByTagName code

Tags: html, excel, vba

Respected Expert, In my URL HTML code the **input** Element is available 5 times,And the Element has been counted as 0 to 4. I want to click **login Button** which is co-related with 4th input element html code. So My Query is if I assigned the value of **i = 3 or i = 4** in both the cases i got the same result which executed the code of 3rd input element code,where I required to execute the 4 input element code which help me to click on **login Button**.In-short My code is stuck on 3rd element button only and not allow me use the further element html code to execute my query.please help me....

```
 Sub GoToWebsiteTest()
    Dim appIE As InternetExplorerMedium
    Dim tags As Object
    Dim tagx As Object
    Dim Element As HTMLButtonElement
    i = 4
    Set appIE = New InternetExplorerMedium
    sURL = "http://myurl/blink/"
    With appIE
        .navigate sURL
            .Visible = True
        End With

        Do While appIE.Busy Or appIE.READYSTATE <> 4
            DoEvents
        Loop

            appIE.document.getElementById("Username").Value = "xxx"
            appIE.document.getElementById("Pwd").Value = "xxxx"
           Set tags = appIE.document.getElementsByTagName("Input")
           tags(i).Click
```

Dear Sir Please find the Below HTML code which contain the 5 input Elements and As u check the 2nd last element is belongs to error massage so as I mention even I assigned the value of **i = 3 or i = 4** in both the cases the **error massage** button is executed and I am not able to execute the last element button of login.

```
<input type="hidden" name="dummyField" id="dummyField" value="">

<input id="userName" name="userName" title="Username" autocomplete="off" onkeypress="if(event.keyCode == 13)
{if(!(document.loginForm.userName.value=='')){document.loginForm.dummyField.value='dummyvalue';}
else{document.loginForm.dummyField.value='';}}">


<input type="password" id="pwd" name="pwd" autocomplete="off" onkeypress="if(event.keyCode == 13)
{if(!(document.loginForm.pwd.value=='' || document.loginForm.userName.value=='' )){return submitenter(this,event)
;}else if(!(document.loginForm.pwd.value=='' &amp;&amp; document.loginForm.userName.value=='' )){document.loginForm.dummyField.value='dummyValue';}
else{document.loginForm.dummyField.value='';}}if(!event.keyCode == 13){if(!(document.loginForm.pwd.value=='' &amp;&amp; document.loginForm.userName.value=='' ))
{document.loginForm.dummyField.value='dummyValue';}else{document.loginForm.dummyField.value='';}}">

<label class="errormessage"></label>
<div style="display: none;">
<input type="submit">

<button onclick="if(!(document.loginForm.pwd.value=='' || document.loginForm.userName.value=='' ))
{ document.loginForm.pwd.value= hex_sha1(document.loginForm.pwd.value);document.loginForm.pwd.value= hex_sha1
(document.loginForm.pwd.value+'HtfWAXkcpfff');javascript:document.loginForm.submit();}validateMandatoryFields();">Login</button>
<div style="display: none;">
<input type="submit">
```

Comment: If `i = 4`, you are clicking the 5th element as you're using the index rather than the occurrence of that element. Try looping through all the `Input` elements and `Debug.Print` their `outerHTML`

Comment: @Jordan Sir, I have tried looping through all the Input elements.but still I am getting the same result, while 4th and 5th loop same window of 4th  element has been appeared twice.please help

Comment: Put the html code here for the login button.  I don't understand what you mean by co-related.  If an input field is being used as a button then it probably has javascript controlling it.

Comment: @Jordan Sir, I have Updated My Question with HTML codes.